# UITableview resize animated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, resize

I want to resize a TableView animated.

I have the following structure

```
TabBarController
--> NavController
---> ViewController
----> TableViewController
```

I tried out this snippet in my ViewController, but unfortunately it removes the NavController and shows the last view of the NavController. The resize it self doesn't work.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 254, 0, 309);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I'm thankfull for every hint.
cheers endo

**EDIT / SOLVED:** I had the animation for testing purposes in the didReceiveMemoryWarning of my view. shame on me, because it works now ^^

Comment: where are you running this code? we need context :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the animation for testing purposes in the didReceiveMemoryWarning of my view. shame on me, because it works now ^^